# Gravityforms+ stripe on Magnificent Popup Ajax

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, magnific-popup, gravity-forms-plugin

I have been working with Gravityforms+ stripe (more) plugin for gravity forms. I currently want to display a stripe-enabled gravity form in a magnific popup (ajax call).

Any other gravity forms work well, however if it involves Stripe, I am getting an error "Your form cannot be processed, please contact the site owner"

In the logs, I can see the following error:

"ERROR --> Empty token"

I am assuming that when calling a gravity form with ajax, some js (stripe.js) is not being called correctly or some script is missing from the ajax call.

Wondering if someone with enough expertise could point me in the right direction on how to (pre) load, requiered gravity forms scripts so that any stripe gravity form would work.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar yet slightly different issue. Your question was the only result when searching "gravity forms stripe 'empty token'".

It turns out that I was trying to use "Gravity Forms + Stripe" (https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-stripe/) which is a third party integration between Stripe and Gravity Forms.

Gravity forms now offer their own Stripe Addon that is only available on their $200/year developer license.

Hope that helps someone.